# Maven test jar including dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-jar-plugin

My project is divided into several modules, one of them is common which is supposed to be used to other modules.

In this module there are TestUtils which I want to be able to use from other modules.

**My libraries does not seem to be added to the test-jar. How can I achieve this?**

```
+ common
++ lib
++ src
+++ test
++++ java
++++ resources
+ pom.xml
```

My pom.xml contains some libraries which I include via system path, such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.disthub2.dhbcore</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.07</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dhbcore.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Not possible. The test-jar is only intended for compiled classes under the folder `src/test/java` inclusive `src/test/resources` but not for supplemental jar files.

Apart from that using a system scope is in general a bad idea.
Best is to put such jars into the company nexus and use it as a usual dependency. A lib folder in a Maven project is generally in indicator of build smells and should be avoided.

BTW: Why are you using such old versions of maven-jar-plugin (2008 version 2.2). [Current version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) version 2.5 from this year.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put them on our nexus and see how it goes from there.